# How to correctly handle exception in background Task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have got an ASP.NET WebApi project.

After invoking one of the actions in my HomeController I start new Task in the background, and return response immediately. It looks something like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(int id)
{
    Task.Run(() => .... someMethod);

    return new SomeViewModel();
}
```

As you can see Im not awaiting for finish of the task, its completely background work.

In my global.asax Im catching all the unhandled exceptions in the project. But when my someMethod invoked in the Task.Run throws an exception, the Application_error event in ASP is not catching it. Why? And how can I properly handle all the exceptions in my background task?

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: Please note that your approach is **strongly discouraged** in ASP.Net. Not only for exception handling, but also because your task may be interrupted *at any time* by IIS. Check [this great article from Scott Hansleman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

According to this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library), you can check on exceptions from tasks by querying the task's Exception property. The following is code pulled from the reference:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var task1 = Task.Run( () => { throw new CustomException("This exception is expected!"); } );

      while(! task1.IsCompleted) {}

      if (task1.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted) {
          foreach (var e in task1.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
              // Handle the custom exception.
              if (e is CustomException) {
                  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
              }
              // Rethrow any other exception.
              else {
                  throw e;
              }
          }
      }
   }
}

public class CustomException : Exception
{
   public CustomException(String message) : base(message)
   {}
}
// The example displays the following output:
//        This exception is expected!
```

Note that the scope of the variable holding the task is persisted sufficiently so its Exception property can be queried. Your example has an implicit local holding the task, which will fall out-of-scope when the return is executed.

-- ss

Comment: "As you can see Im not awaiting for finish of the task, its completely background work.". If they wanted to actually wait for the task to complete before returning they could just wrap a try/catch around `Task.Wait()` and would catch the exception without all this extra code.  But that isn't what they are asking.

Comment: The task must be persisted in a variable, perhaps of class scope, that will allow the TaskFaulted and Exception properties to be queried.